# How can I make my delete function work in my todo app?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

### I am making a todo app. In the app, there are delete and edit functions. But the Delete function works at the first todo. If I try other todos, It deletes a lot of todos. I tried many ways but disn't work. Please help!

```js
const todoForm = document.querySelector(".todo-form");
const todos = document.querySelector(".todos");
const todoTitle = document.querySelector(".todo-title");
const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");
const modalClose = document.querySelector(".close-button");
const editedText = document.querySelector(".edited-text ");
const submitEdit = document.querySelector(".submit");

const todoList = [];
let totalTodo = 0;

function findFromArray(id, array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (id === array[i].id) {
      return array[i];
    }
  }

  return null;
}

function deleteTodo(id) {
  const element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.remove();
  const data = findFromArray(id, todoList);
  todoList.splice(todoList.indexOf(data), 1);
}

function editTodo(id) {
  const element = document.querySelector("#" + id + " h1");
  modal.showModal();
  modalClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
    modal.close();
  });
  submitEdit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const newTodoText = editedText.value;
    element.innerText = newTodoText;
    modal.close();
  });
}

todoForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let title = todoTitle.value;

  const newTodo = document.createElement("div");
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  const editButton = document.createElement("button");

  deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";

  todoList.push({
    id: "Todo" + totalTodo,
    title,
  });

  totalTodo++;

  for (let i = 0; i < todoList.length; i++) {
    newTodo.classList.add("todo-card");
    todos.appendChild(newTodo);

    h1.innerText = todoList[i].title;
    deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => deleteTodo(todoList[i].id));
    editButton.addEventListener("click", () => editTodo(todoList[i].id));

    newTodo.appendChild(h1);
    newTodo.appendChild(deleteButton);
    newTodo.appendChild(editButton);
    newTodo.id = todoList[i].id;
  }
  todoTitle.value = "";
});
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 class="todo-heading">Todo App</h1>
  <form class="todo-form">
    <input class="todo-title" type="text" placeholder="Todo Name" />

    <input type="Submit" class="todo-button" />
  </form>
  <br />
  <div class="todos"></div>
  <dialog id="modal">
    <h1>Edit</h1>
    <input type="text" class="edited-text" placeholder="New Todo" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    <button class="close-button">
        <svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
          <path
            d="M10.185,1.417c-4.741,0-8.583,3.842-8.583,8.583c0,4.74,3.842,8.582,8.583,8.582S18.768,14.74,18.768,10C18.768,5.259,14.926,1.417,10.185,1.417 M10.185,17.68c-4.235,0-7.679-3.445-7.679-7.68c0-4.235,3.444-7.679,7.679-7.679S17.864,5.765,17.864,10C17.864,14.234,14.42,17.68,10.185,17.68 M10.824,10l2.842-2.844c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.46,0-0.637c-0.177-0.178-0.461-0.178-0.637,0l-2.844,2.841L7.341,6.52c-0.176-0.178-0.46-0.178-0.637,0c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637L9.546,10l-2.841,2.844c-0.178,0.176-0.178,0.461,0,0.637c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0l2.844-2.841l2.844,2.841c0.178,0.178,0.459,0.178,0.637,0c0.178-0.176,0.178-0.461,0-0.637L10.824,10z"
          ></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
  </dialog>
```

#### I was expecting to remove a todo element and the todo data. But It removes a lot of todo elements and data. I tried the splice method and the delete keyword but didn't work. Please help!

Comment: Didn't you see the errors in the console?

Comment: I saw this error: Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at deleteTodo (index.js:28:12)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.js:68:50)

Comment: That error relates to your reassigning of the variable todoList which you declare as 'constant' on line 9 of your snippet. You should probably want to remove the 'todoList = ' bit in the deleteTodo function though, as splice() modifies the array in place, what is returned is what is deleted.

Comment: Oh! Didn't notice that. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the for loop you are using to create the new elements. The loop is iterating through the entire `todoList` array, but it should only be creating a new todo element for the last array item.

```js
todoForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let title = todoTitle.value;

  const newTodo = document.createElement("div");
  const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  const editButton = document.createElement("button");

  deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";

  todoList.push({
    id: "Todo" + totalTodo,
    title,
  });

  totalTodo++;

  const lastTodo = todoList[todoList.length - 1];

  newTodo.classList.add("todo-card");
  todos.appendChild(newTodo);

  h1.innerText = lastTodo.title;
  deleteButton.addEventListener("click", () => deleteTodo(lastTodo.id));
  editButton.addEventListener("click", () => editTodo(lastTodo.id));

  newTodo.appendChild(h1);
  newTodo.appendChild(deleteButton);
  newTodo.appendChild(editButton);
  newTodo.id = lastTodo.id;
  todoTitle.value = "";
});
```

Also, like **Jelmer** commented.. In the deleteTodo function, remove `todoList =`. You should use the splice method directly on the todoList array to remove the element.

```js
todoList.splice(todoList.indexOf(data), 1);
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thank you so much!